# Ubuntu is slow to boot. How do I identify the problem?

Tags: systemd

I'm running Ubuntu 17 on an old pc. The `systemd-analyze blame` shows that some service takes a lot of time to start. How can avoid this? There are some service that I can disable?

```
         27.063s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         11.301s apparmor.service
         10.765s motd-news.service
         10.572s dev-sda5.device
          7.742s NetworkManager.service
          7.548s ModemManager.service
          7.073s udisks2.service
          6.593s accounts-daemon.service
          6.491s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          6.475s snapd.service
          4.167s plymouth-read-write.service
          4.083s thermald.service
          3.742s polkit.service
          3.722s gpu-manager.service
          3.646s preload.service
          3.590s rsyslog.service
          2.474s apport.service
          2.473s grub-common.service
          2.169s postfix@-.service
          2.035s fwupd.service
          1.818s colord.service
          1.758s avahi-daemon.service
          1.653s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
          1.494s resolvconf.service
          1.375s networking.service
          1.375s packagekit.service
          1.343s gdm.service
          1.214s systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
          1.037s bluetooth.service
           988ms speech-dispatcher.service
           904ms console-setup.service
           889ms systemd-udevd.service
           838ms keyboard-setup.service
           834ms wpa_supplicant.service
           642ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           606ms systemd-modules-load.service
           578ms dns-clean.service
           564ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
           537ms plymouth-start.service
           528ms pppd-dns.service
           472ms systemd-logind.service
           466ms user@124.service
           439ms swapfile.swap
           359ms systemd-update-utmp.service
           357ms systemd-random-seed.service
           339ms tlp.service
           312ms alsa-restore.service
           296ms dev-hugepages.mount
           295ms dev-mqueue.mount
           294ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           276ms systemd-journald.service
           220ms upower.service
           195ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           192ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           164ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           139ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
           127ms systemd-user-sessions.service
           119ms systemd-sysctl.service
           108ms setvtrgb.service
            93ms kerneloops.service
            68ms user@1000.service
            64ms ufw.service
            57ms snapd.socket
            37ms systemd-remount-fs.service
            24ms rtkit-daemon.service
            12ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             2ms sys-kernel-config.mount
```

Comment: Many of these units should not take that long to start. Please [edit] your question and provide more details about what your system configuration actually is (CPU, RAM, disk specs, whether BIOS is set to IDE or AHCI for SATA if used), so that someone may be able to provide better help.

Comment: Please add the output of `inxi -SMGD -! 31 -y 80` Maybe the problem is [a bug on `plymouth-start.service`](https://superuser.com/a/487446/500826)